# How to scale 2D object periodically?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am attempting to have a variable scale factor, so that each frame the scaling changes by + or - .05, which gives it a growing/shrinking animation aspect.

My scaling factors (scale_x, scale_y, and scale_z) are initialized to 1.0. What I want to happen is for each frame rendered, each scale factor will grow or shrink by some fixed value (like .05). Ideally, at first it should keep subtracting .05 every frame until it reaches a fixed value, like 0.2. Then I would like it to start growing from 0.2 up to 1.0 again.

It should give the illusion of shrinking and growing over time.
I'm struggling with coming up with a way to do this. I was thinking of using some sort of boolean value "grow" that tells me whether or not I should grow (add .05 to each factor), or shrink (subtract .05 from each factor).

```
// These are global vars.
float rotate_x, rotate_y, rotate_z;
float scale_x = 1.0f;
float scale_y = 1.0f;
float scale_z = 1.0f;
...

void update_scale()
{
// what can go here?
}

void animate()
{
// calculate new transformation values
update_rotation();
update_scale();

//apply transformations
glRotatef(rotate_x, 1, 0, 0);
glRotatef(rotate_y, 0, 1, 0);
glRotatef(rotate_z, 0, 0, 1);
glScalef(scale_x, scale_y, scale_z);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep an additional variable that tracks the current increment you apply to your scale factor, and inverse it every time you reach your upper/lower limit.

Based on a couple of constants:

```
const float MIN_SCALE = 0.2f;
const float MAX_SCALE = 1.0f;
const float SCALE_STEP = 0.05f;
```

Then initialize:

```
float scaleFact = MAX_SCALE;
float scaleInc = -SCALE_STEP;
```

Then on each update:

```
scaleFact += scaleInc;
if (scaleFact < MIN_SCALE + 0.5f * SCALE_STEP) {
    scaleFact = MIN_SCALE;
    scaleInc = SCALE_STEP;
} else if (scaleFact > MAX_SCALE - 0.5f * SCALE_STEP) {
    scaleFact = MAX_SCALE;
    scaleInc = -SCALE_STEP;
}
```

The above does some tweaking to the tests to avoid comparing float values that are almost equal. Instead of dealing with possibly problematic float comparisons, you could use an integer variable to keep track of the progress, and multiply it to get the actual scale factor.